# MBR2GPT validation failing

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, mbr, gpt

Same issue as:[MBR2GPT: Disk layout validation failed for disk 0](https://superuser.com/questions/1384946/mbr2gpt-disk-layout-validation-failed-for-disk-0)

I've tried all of the solutions here. [This is my diskpart and MBR2GPT log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUfjR.png). [This is my Disk management window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vans.png). As you can see, I have less than 3 partitions, and have 16gb unallocated space for use.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the entire Disk Management window.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vans.png

Comment: Your problem is that you're booting from Disk 0, but trying to convert Disk 1. MBR2GPT will not work when the boot is split over two disks. You will need to do some dangerous partition work to correct the issue. Why is doing this conversion so important?

Comment: I'm not booting from disk 0. Disk 1 is an SSD with my entire system on it. Disk 0 is a hard drive with miscellaneous files. I'm not sure why the names are mismatched, but that's definitely not the problem.

Comment: You're booting from the "System Reserved" partition on Disk 0, which directs the boot to Disk 1. This partition must be copied to Disk 1 and the BIOS to be set to boot from it, before the conversion. Do you wish to do these manipulations? But you haven't answered my question about why you're doing this.

Comment: This was for Windows 11, but at this point I might just look into skipping Secure Boot.

Comment: That might be more prudent. The above manipulations are possible and documented, but partition work is risky.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help.

Comment: While you can disable TPM 2.0 and CPU checks with `AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU`, but you will NOT be able to skip the GPT requirement.  **Windows 11 does not actually support MBR.** At least not without modifying the ISO to support it.

Comment: This^^^So the best course of action is to start with a GPT drive.